# Load denied by X-Frame-Options: does not permit cross-origin framing

Tags: php, laravel-4, cors

I am using laravel 4 for one of my development where i am trying to load an iframe using cross origin call. But it throws an error like "Load denied by X-Frame-Options: does not permit cross-origin framing".

I am trying to set a headers like:

```
header('X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM SAMEORIGIN');
header('X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM GOFORIT');
```

But still i am getting the above issue. Please suggest if i am missing something.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Answer (score 8):

When you use `ALLOW-FROM` you have to specify a URL, not an alternative value.

Using `SAMEORIGIN` explicitly blocks cross origin calls.

When using that or `GOFORIT` you have to specify that as the only value.

So you want:

```
header("X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT");
```

Note that `GOFORIT` is the *default* behaviour, so you will probably have to remove some other code that is denying access.

Note also that the `X-Frame-Options` header must grant permission **from the page being displayed in the frame** and not the page containing the `<iframe>` tag itself. You can't give yourself permission to put other sites in a frame.